# System.Text.Json.Serialization replacement for Netwtonsoft's JsonObjectAttribute NamingStrategy setting

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, json.net, system.text.json

For those of you who have done more .NET 6 than me, have you found a replacement for [Netwonsoft's JsonObjectAttribute's NamingStrategy setting](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/NamingStrategyAttributes.htm)?

```
[JsonObject(NamingStrategyType = typeof(CamelCaseNamingStrategy))]
public class PortConfig
{
    public string Http { get; set; }
    public string Https { get; set; }
}
```

I want something that I can stamp on the **CLASS** to declare its property's naming strategy, rather than having to put a `JsonPropertyName("CamelCaseName")` attribute on each property.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-customize-properties?pivots=dotnet-6-0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass options to the serializer

```
var options = new System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions
{
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase
};
```

Or in your startup you can configure the default

```
.AddJsonOptions(opts =>
{
    opts.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
})
```

Another option is to use `JsonSourceGenerationOptions` if you don't want to configure it globally or use serializer options

[How to use source generation in System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-source-generation?pivots=dotnet-6-0)

```
[JsonSourceGenerationOptions(PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonKnownNamingPolicy.CamelCase)]
public class PortConfig
{
    public string Http { get; set; }
    public string Https { get; set; }
}
```

If you need to build a custom naming class the documentation is here
[Custom Json Property Naming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0)

Comment: The last option is what I was looking for! Thanks for that!

I'm disappointed to see only CamelCase is supported for JsonKnownNamingPolicy though. No snake case or pascal? Weird.

Comment: You can build your own custom serializers as well. There is a page on migrating from Newtonsoft [Migrating from NewtonSoft Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0)